# Why is a NoClassDefFound error not being fixed with upgraded dependency versions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependencies, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade an existing spring boot service from 1.4.0 to 2.2.7. I have updated my pom to point the the appropriate version for multiple dependencies and have also changed the name of the others which have been restructured.

Here is my pom:

```
...
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-localconfig-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Distributed Tracing -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
            <!-- netty's native is pulled, but is useless unless you explicitly
                add the native binary dependency. Having it in the classpath without the
                binary can cause warnings -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
        DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(app);
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
        //some code
}
```

When I start the application, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.comcast.xfinity.mobile.config.SecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@2b3adcc1]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:743) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1608) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:526) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:497) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:611) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1242) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:869) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:857) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:844) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:795) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.comcast.xfinity.mobile.MobileBackOfficeGatewayApp.main(MobileBackOfficeGatewayApp.java:85) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/query/spi/EvaluationContextExtensionSupport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.query.spi.EvaluationContextExtensionSupport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

I am not sure how to fix this transitive dependency. From what I understand the `EvaluationContextExtensionSupport` class has been deprecated in the later versions of spring. But since I am not making use of this class directly in my application and all others depencecies seem to be upgraded to the correct version, I am not sure how to proceed further.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit(s):

1. Included spring-cloud version in the pom
2. Included `dependencyManagement` section in pom

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.1.14.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/spi/EvaluationContextExtensionSupport.html  - it's long deprecated and may have since been removed. Probably one of the dependencies in the ... of your snippet is still using that class.

Comment: Thanks, you're probably right. Let me try to weed through that. Maybe that will help narrow down

Comment: There are a lot of dependencies in there, some of which you don't need as they are already pulled in. You are also using Spring Cloud and Spring Cloud versions are tied to certain Spring Boot versions so you need to update Spring Cloud as well.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the spring cloud version. ```<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>``` I checked for compatibility in the docs and this supports 2.2.7

Comment: Please include your full `pom.xml` as there are parts missing. Either hardcoded versions, dependencyManagement section etc. As I also stated there are dependencies in there that shouldn't be in there as well.

Comment: The pom file is quite large, about 1500 lines, and stack overflow does not let me post something that large. Let me try to remove some of the redundancies and see if that helps.

Comment: I have added the dependecyManagement section to the pom in the meanwhile